# How can I change the intensity of a colormap in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I use [matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pcolor#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) to plot a heatmap with matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

np.random.seed(1)
data =  np.sort(np.random.rand(8,12))
plt.figure()
c = plt.pcolor(data, edgecolors='k', linewidths=4, cmap='RdBu', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
plt.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I change the intensity of the `'RdBu'` colormap? E.g., if the color is `(0, 0, 1)`, it should be transformed into `(0, 0, 0.8)`. More generally, 
if the color is `(x, y, z)`, it should be transformed into `(ax, ay, az)`, where `a` is some scalar between zero and one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is quite similar to Stanley R's (edit: now Serenity) answer, without the (in my opinion) unnecessary complexity of loops, appending to lists, et cetera:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

a = 0.5

# Get the colormap colors, multiply them with the factor "a", and create new colormap
my_cmap = plt.cm.RdBu(np.arange(plt.cm.RdBu.N))
my_cmap[:,0:3] *= a 
my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_cmap)

np.random.seed(1)
data =  np.sort(np.random.rand(8,12))
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
c = plt.pcolor(data, edgecolors='k', linewidths=4, cmap='RdBu', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
plt.colorbar(c)
plt.subplot(122)
c = plt.pcolor(data, edgecolors='k', linewidths=4, cmap=my_cmap, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
plt.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to assembly new custom color map based on a standard.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

np.random.seed(1)
data =  np.sort(np.random.rand(8,12))
plt.figure()
cmap = cm.get_cmap('RdBu', len(data)) # set how many colors you want in color map
# modify colormap
alpha = .5
colors = []
for ind in xrange(cmap.N):
    c = []
    for x in cmap(ind)[:3]: c.append(x*alpha)
    colors.append(tuple(c))
my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors, name = 'my_name')
# plot with my new cmap
cb = plt.pcolor(data, edgecolors='k', linewidths=4, cmap=my_cmap, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
plt.colorbar(cb)
plt.show()
```

[image]